# Link for a specific role to add content

Tags: routes, users, nodes

I have created a menu for a specific role, how i can add a link, so the role could create content ?(I dont want this role to have administration menu, just a normal menu).

Comment: You don't have to have a different link for particular user role. You can give permission to a particular user role to add content. The add content link will be available based on permission too. Check this out in admin/people/permissions

Comment: check this https://drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility

Comment: I have given theese permissions to the role, i have loged in as role but i dont see any links to add content,

,"mycont: Create new content",
,"mycont: Edit own content",
,"mycont: Delete own content"

Comment: Then add an item to the menu like 'node/add/content_type', The user with assigned role can see the link and add content.

Comment: That works, Thank you very much :D
put your comment as answer so i can make thumbs up !!!